# Retorno de valor de variable

Tags: java, netbeans, variables

Estoy haciendo una simulación de pizzería, tengo una clase llamada "Pizza" y en esa clase declaro el valor inicial de la cuenta que es de $0.Al elegir un tamaño de pizza (Chica, mediana etc) te calcula cuanto es el costo(Clase diferente de pizza) este valor lo tengo que usar una vez calculado por si llega a querer hacer otro pedido se le sumaria al valor de cuenta (88(pedido1)+88(pedido2))=176, pero este valor se retome siempre en la clase principal (menu) y siempre reimprime el valor de 0 y no el que se le debería haber sumado.
Lo que yo pensé hacer fue:

public int TamañoVegetariana(){

```
    int tamaño;
           
    System.out.println("Estos son los tamaños de las pizzas:");
    System.out.println("1.-Mediano ($88)");
    System.out.println("2.-Grande ($97)");
    System.out.println("3.-Familiar ($111)");
    System.out.println("4.-Extra familiar con parmesano ($156)");
    System.out.println("¿Que tamaño quiere?");
    tamaño = xy.nextInt();
    
    switch (tamaño){
        
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Su pizza sera de 4 cortes");
            this.cuenta += 88;
            System.out.println("Su cuenta es de " +cuenta);
            break;
            
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Su pizza sera de 8 cortes");
            this.cuenta += 97;
            System.out.println("Su cuenta es de " +cuenta);
            break;
            
        case 3: 
            System.out.println("Su pizza sera de 12 cortes");
            this.cuenta += 111;
            System.out.println("Su cuenta es de " +cuenta);
            break;
            
        case 4:
            System.out.println("Su pizza sera de 16 cortes");
            this.cuenta += 156;
            System.out.println("Su cuenta es de " +cuenta);
            break;
        
    }
    return cuenta;
}
```

Pero al momento de llamar el valor de cuenta me marca que tiene valor de 0, necesito que haga la cuenta total sin importar el numero de pizzas.[image]

Este es el codigo donde debe imprimir el valor de los pedidos realizados pero marca 0.

```
case 3:
                    piza = new Vegetariana();
                    piza.Hornear();
                    piza.Cortar();
                    piza.Empacar();
                    Vegetariana veg = new Vegetariana();
                    veg.OpcionVege();  
                    veg.TamañoVegetariana();
                    System.out.println(getCuenta());
                    break;
```

Comment: Ese metodo getCuenta de que clase es.

Answer (score 0):

Porque creas un nuevo objeto de la clase Vegetariana?
del metodo TamañoVegetariana estas llamando devuelta a ese metodo

```
Vegetariana veg = new Vegetariana();
veg.OpcionVege();  
veg.TamañoVegetariana();
```

Y en el metodo getCuenta() tendrias que hacer algo asi,

```
private int cuenta;

public int getCuenta(){
    return cuenta;
} 

public void sumarTamañoFamiliar(){
    cuenta = cuenta + 111 //tamaño familiar
}
```

Llamarias a sumarTamañoFamiliar() eso le suma al int el precio y luego lo obtienes con getCuenta(), aun así creo que el problema es que de el metodo TamañoVegetariana estas llamando devuelta a TamañoVegetariana() de la misma clase